# How to get the previous and next elements of an array loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

In a simple array loop of Javacript as

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {

var previous=array[i-1];
var current=array[i];
var next=array[i+1];

}
```

I need to get the `previous` and `next` elements in an unlimited cycle. For example,

```
The previous element of the first element in the array is the array last element
The next element of the last element in the array is the array first element
```

What can be the most efficient way to do this. The only way I can think of is to check if the element is the first or last in the array in every round.

In fact, I hope to make the array a closed cycle somehow, rather than linear.

Comment: "make the array a closed cycle" - that's not possible. You could maybe implement some kind of ring-buffer like structure using objects, but arrays are always linear.

Comment: @lethal-guitar I know it is not the nature of an array, I said literally.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

as you're talking about "unlimited cycle" I assume your loop is something like that

```
var i = 0,
    l = array.length;

while( true ) // keep looping
{
    if(i >= l) i = 0;

    // the loop block

    if(/* something to cause the loop to end */) break; // <-- this let execution exit the loop immediately

    i+=1;
}
```

---

The **most efficient way** to achieve your goal is the naive one: **checking**

```
    var previous=array[i==0?array.length-1:i-1];
    var current=array[i];
    var next=array[i==array.length-1?0:i+1];
```

obviously cache the length of the array in a variable

```
var l = array.length;
```

and (better style) the "vars" out of the cycle

```
var previuos,
    current,
    next;
```

---

Note that if you are accessing the array **read only** there would be a faster (but somewhat strange) way:

```
l = array.length;
array[-1] = array[l-1]; // this is legal
array[l] = array[0];

for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    previous = array[i-1];
    current = array[i];
    next = array[i+1];
}

// restore the array

array.pop(); 
array[-1] = null;
```

Comment: correct "var previuos" to "var previous"

Answer (score 92):

Use [modulus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) :

```
var len = array.length;

var current = array[i];
var previous = array[(i+len-1)%len];
var next = array[(i+1)%len];
```

Note the `+len` when getting the previous: the reason we need this is to avoid negative indexes, due to the way modulus works (very unfortunately, `-x%` is `-(x%)`)

Answer (score 8):

To add to @Denys answer - this is how you can create a reuseable function

```
var theArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var currentIndex = 0;

function getAtIndex(i) {
    if (i === 0) {
        return theArray[currentIndex];
    } else if (i < 0) {
        return theArray[(currentIndex + theArray.length + i) % theArray.length];
    } else if (i > 0) {
        return theArray[(currentIndex + i) % theArray.length];
    }
}

// usage
getAtIndex(-2)

// you can even go crazy and it still works
getAtIndex(500)
```

[Demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/xL9349jq/)

Answer (score 5):

To make it simple.

for the next element in array:

```
 currentIndex= (currentIndex+1)%array.length;
```

for the previous element in array:

```
currentIndex= (currentIndex+array.length-1)%array.length;
```

Answer (score 4):

you need reduce; a built sweet function to get previous and next values of array

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

for more info about **[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

Edit: add some function signatures and more info below

```
reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) { /* … */ }, initialValue)
reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) { /* … */ }, initialValue)
reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) { /* … */ }, initialValue)
```

#### [Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters)

- `accumulator`
  - : The value resulting from the previous call to `callbackFn`. On first call, `initialValue` if specified, otherwise the value of `array[0]`.
- `currentValue`
  - : The value of the current element. On first call, the value of `array[0]` if an `initialValue` was specified, otherwise the value of `array[1]`.
- `currentIndex`
  - : The index position of `currentValue` in the array. On first call, `0` if `initialValue` was specified, otherwise `1`.
- `array`
  - : The array `reduce()` was called upon.
- `initialValue` *Optional*

  - : A value to which `accumulator` is initialized the first time the callback is called.
    If `initialValue` is specified, `callbackFn` starts executing with the first value in the array as `currentValue`.
    If `initialValue` is *not* specified, `accumulator` is initialized to the first value in the array, and `callbackFn` starts executing with the second value in the array as `currentValue`. In this case, if the array is empty (so that there's no first value to return as `accumulator`), an error is thrown.

#### Return value

The value that results from running the "reducer" callback function to completion over the entire array.

ref:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters

Comment: To clarify, `previousValue` is actually an `accumulator`, as it's not the previous array value, but what was returned from the prior callback invocation.