# Getting distance between two points inside a 2d array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, distance

I am tyring to get the distance between hillArray[i][0]) and hillArray[i+1][0]).
I do realize that when the loop reaches the last interaction the point hillArray[i+1][0]) will be invalid. I am not sure how to fix that problem.

This is my code to generate the points

```
function randomMap(numOfHills){
    hillArray.push([ xMap*0,yMap]);
    for(var i=0; i<numOfHills; i++){
        xRandomForHills = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000));
        if(xRandomForHills >= 950){
            xRandomForHills = xRandomForHills - 10;
        }
        if(xRandomForHills <= 50){
            xRandomForHills = xRandomForHills + 10;
        }
        yRandomForHills = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300));
        if(yRandomForHills <= 10){
            yRandomForHills = yRandomForHills + 30;
        }
        hillArray.push([xRandomForHills,yRandomForHills]);

    }
    hillArray.push([xMap,yMap]);
    sortArray(numOfHills);
};
```

And this is my code to track the distances. [i+1] is the mistake or at least I think it is.

```
function baseDist(){
    baseDist = [];
    var xDistanceCheck;
    var yDistanceCheck;
    var distance = 0;

        for(var i=0;i<=hillArray.length;i++){

                FIRST C-A
                console.log("_________________________________");
                xDistanceCheck = hillArray[i][0]) - (hillArray[i][0]);
                xDistanceCheck = xDistanceCheck * xDistanceCheck;
                yDistanceCheck = hillArray[i][1] - (hillArray[i][1]);
                yDistanceCheck = yDistanceCheck * yDistanceCheck;
                distance = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(xDistanceCheck + yDistanceCheck));
                baseDist.push([distance])
                console.log(" Point " + hillArray[i][0]) " to point " + (hillArray[i+1][0]) + baseDist[0]);

                console.log("Last C-A  = " + baseDist[i]);


        }
};
```

Comment: Make the code simple so that we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I used module...

```
var l = array.length;

var current = array[i];
var previous = array[(i+l-1)%l];
var next = array[(i+1)%l];
```

found the answer on [How to get the previous and next elements of an array loop in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388291/how-to-get-the-previous-and-next-elements-of-an-array-loop-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the formula to calculate distance between two points

**Formula is**

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(x1-x2),2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(y1-y2),2)+ Math.pow(Math.abs(z1-z2),2))
```

Comment: What formula is that ?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.