# How to get the next entry for a fixed entry in an array in html

Tags: javascript, html

Assume we have the array

> [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h].

I want to write a function that randomly take a value in my array.
I have already written this in JS and HTML.

My question is this:
I want the previously and the next letter for the chosen one.

For example we get "e". Then I want a function that returns "d" and "f".
How can I do this?

My code is below. (My js.file is named "nyNumber.js").

```js
function GetValue() {
  var myarray = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h");

  var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
  //alert(random);
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Give me" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="message"></p>

<script src="myNumber.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is the php tag relevant?

Comment: what about the items who have no value before or after?

Comment: your array definition is an array of `undefined` variables, to begin with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the previous and next elements of an array loop in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388291/how-to-get-the-previous-and-next-elements-of-an-array-loop-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering a closed loop, left of first element is not present so this will give you last element as left of first element and right of last element is not present so this will give you first element as right of last element.

```js
var myarray = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h");
var random;

document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].addEventListener("click", function (){
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length);
  document.getElementsByClassName("itemValue")[0].innerHTML = myarray[random];
  document.getElementsByClassName("siblings")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
})

document.getElementsByClassName("siblings")[0].addEventListener("click", function (){
  var left = myarray[ (random - 1 + myarray.length) % myarray.length ];
  
    var right= myarray[ (random + 1) % myarray.length ];
    
  document.getElementsByClassName("leftSiblingValue")[0].innerHTML = left;
  document.getElementsByClassName("rightSiblingValue")[0].innerHTML = right;
})
```

```html
<button class="item">item</button>
<button class="siblings" disabled>siblings</button>

<p><span>left siblign : </span><span class="leftSiblingValue"><span></p>
<p><span>item : </span><span class="itemValue"></span></p>
<p><span>right sibling : </span><span class="rightSiblingValue"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed one function to give me say "b", when I press a button. And then I need another function to give me "a" and "c", when I press another button. I don't know how to write this.

Comment: hey @OlePetersen, I have updated the answer. I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have strings in your array, you could take just the index and an offset for getting the left and right values of a given random index.

Values of indices who are not in the array show up with `undefined`.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length),
    left = array[random - 1],
    item = array[random],
    right = array[random + 1];
    
console.log(left || 'no left value', item, right || 'no right value');
```

Comment: it print an undefined if `'a'` or `'h'`

Comment: might be useful checking that the `-1` and `+1` actually exist

Answer (score 1):

you should save the value of the random index in a variable to get to the other indices,
but of course you should check if it has a before and after.

```
function GetValue()
{
   var myarray= new Array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);
   var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length);
   var random = myarray[index];
   //alert(random);
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
   return index;
}
```

now you can get the value and get elements depending to it.

Comment: I want to divide it in two, ie I have two buttons on my page. One button gives me the random letter and the other button gives me the one before and the one after. So I guess we need 2 functions for this.

Comment: @OlePetersen ok so use the returned value from this function and get it's before and after value, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

use `Array.prototype.indexOf` [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var myArray = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

var value = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
console.log("First Value:", value);

var position = myArray.indexOf(value);

var next = myArray[position + 1];
console.log("Next Value:", next);

var before = myArray[position - 1];
console.log("Before Value:", before);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myarray = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h");
var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
//alert(random);
var position = myarray.indexOf(random);
var previousElement= myarray[position-1];
var nextElement= myarray[position+1];
console.log(previousElement);
console.log(nextElement);
```

A simple solution is to get the position of your random value using `indexOf` function and just move your array pointer 1 position behind and 1 forward. This will give you the values you need.

Comment: Thanks. I have written this in my JS document. How would you write the reference in html?

Comment: Like you did. Create a function and call it on an event. Or you can call it on document.ready, when the pages load actually.